# Why does adding a Flex DateChooser component throw an index out of bounds error?

Tags: apache-flex, flex4

I'm facing an issue with the flex Application I'm currently working on.
When I open a pop-up using the 'createPopUp' method, I've got this index out of bounds error message :

> RangeError: The supplied index is out of bounds.  at
>   mx.core::FTETextField/getLineMetrics()[E:\dev\4.y\frameworks\projects\spark\src\mx\core\FTETextField.as:2169]
>     at mx.core::UIFTETextField/get
>   baselinePosition()[E:\dev\4.y\frameworks\projects\spark\src\mx\core\UIFTETextField.as:784]
>     at mx.controls::DateChooser/get
>   baselinePosition()[E:\dev\4.y\frameworks\projects\mx\src\mx\controls\DateChooser.as:994]
>     at spark.components::Group/get
>   baselinePosition()[E:\dev\4.y\frameworks\projects\spark\src\spark\components\Group.as:282]
>     at
>   spark.layouts::ConstraintLayout/parseElementConstraints()[E:\dev\4.y\frameworks\projects\spark\src\spark\layouts\ConstraintLayout.as:1818]
>     at
>   spark.layouts::ConstraintLayout/parseConstraints()[E:\dev\4.y\frameworks\projects\spark\src\spark\layouts\ConstraintLayout.as:1632]
>     at
>   spark.layouts::ConstraintLayout/measure()[E:\dev\4.y\frameworks\projects\spark\src\spark\layouts\ConstraintLayout.as:414]
>     at
>   spark.components.supportClasses::GroupBase/measure()[E:\dev\4.y\frameworks\projects\spark\src\spark\components\supportClasses\GroupBase.as:1148]
>     at
>   mx.core::UIComponent/http://www.adobe.com/2006/flex/mx/internal::measureSizes()[E:\dev\4.y\frameworks\projects\framework\src\mx\core\UIComponent.as:8506]
>     at
>   mx.core::UIComponent/validateSize()[E:\dev\4.y\frameworks\projects\framework\src\mx\core\UIComponent.as:8430]
>     at
>   spark.components::Group/validateSize()[E:\dev\4.y\frameworks\projects\spark\src\spark\components\Group.as:1012]
>     at
>   mx.managers::LayoutManager/validateClient()[E:\dev\4.y\frameworks\projects\framework\src\mx\managers\LayoutManager.as:987]
>     at
>   mx.managers::PopUpManagerImpl/addPopUp()[E:\dev\4.y\frameworks\projects\framework\src\mx\managers\PopUpManagerImpl.as:382]
>     at
>   mx.managers::PopUpManagerImpl/createPopUp()[E:\dev\4.y\frameworks\projects\framework\src\mx\managers\PopUpManagerImpl.as:232]
>     at
>   mx.managers::PopUpManager$/createPopUp()[E:\dev\4.y\frameworks\projects\framework\src\mx\managers\PopUpManager.as:139]    at
>   views::AddProjects/loadAddProjectPopUp()[C:\Users\Laura\Web\spidermak\spidermak\src\views\AddProjects.mxml:184]
>     at
>   views::AddProjects/___AddProjects_Button1_click()[C:\Users\Laura\Web\spidermak\spidermak\src\views\AddProjects.mxml:838]

It seems that this error is caused by a "dateChooser" component in my popup :

```
<mx:DateChooser id="endDate"/>
```

When I comment this line, the error is no longer thrown and the popup loads correctly.

It's really weird because I didn't have this issue until this morning. All I did in the meantime was changing some layout-related stuff, but I don't see what is would have to do with this problem.
I don't get it...

Does anyone have a clue about how to fix this ? I need my DateChooser !

Thanks !

Laura

- EDIT -

It seems that the problem is not caused by the DateChooser itself, but by the FormItem around it. Here's what my code looks like :

```
<Form width="100%">
[...]
    <s:HGroup width="100%">
        <s:FormItem label="Date de début">
            <mx:DateChooser id="startDate" 
                    firstDayOfWeek="1"/>
        </s:FormItem>

        <s:FormItem label="Date de fin">
            <mx:DateChooser id="endDate"
                    firstDayOfWeek="1"/>
        </s:FormItem>
    </s:HGroup>
</Form>
```

If I remove the two FormItems, it works. Could anyone explain me why? Thanks !

Answer (score 1):

Try wrapping the component in a `<s:Group>` element, i.e.

```
<s:FormItem label="Start date">
    <s:Group>
        <mx:DateChooser id="startDate"
            firstDayOfWeek="1" />
    </s:Group>
</s:FormItem>
```

Apparently, it's something to do with the composition of Spark components. lolFlex.

(I had exactly the same problem, and couldn't find any solution on the interwebs either!)

Answer (score 0):

I think you should upgrade to the latest TLF. This reminds me of a bug in TLF 1.x. Try 2.x.

Comment: Thank you for your answer Florian. I'm pretty new to flex and don't know about TLF, will do some research about it. If my problem is related to this, why didn't it happen until today ?

Comment: That's the problems with bugs. Some might just come up because of side effects or when a functionality is used in a specific way.